# Android Studio 3.0 Canary 8: Advanced profiling is unavailable for the selected process

Tags: java, android, android-studio

On Android Studio 3.0 Canary 3 if I remember correctly advanced profiling worked without problems, once it was enabled in the run configuration. However after upgrading to AS 3 Canary 8 even if I enable advanced profiling, clean, rebuild and deploy to a Google Pixel running Android 7.1.2 the Android Profiler keeps telling me, that "Advanced profiling is unavailable for the selected process".

In the run configuration it also says:

Enable advanced profiling (required for API level < 26 only)

so I raised my compile SDK to 26 - but still no luck. The application is a multi-dex application in case that is relevant.

Any suggestions as to what I am missing or whether this is a known issue in Canary 8 would be highly appreciated.

Note: The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/android-profiler.html#advanced-profiling) states that enabling will slow down my build speed, but it doesn't seem to have any impact on my build speed, which makes me wonder if the setting is ignored.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally got it to work by doing the following:

- Leave compile SDK at 26
- In the run configuration have "Enable advanced profiling" activated, even though it states this is only needed for API level < 26
- Disable Proguard (this seems to be the most important)