# How to display network request list in android sdk profiler?

Tags: android, android-profiler

So I current can profile an apk and view the network graph as follow:

[image]

I am also seeing `Advanced profiling is unavailable for the selected process` which is weird b/c i have it turned on.

I cannot drag my cursor across the graph to inspect, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

- In the run configuration have "Enable advanced profiling" activated, even though it states this is only needed for API level < 26
- Disable Proguard (this seems to be the most important)

From: [Android Studio 3.0 Canary 8: Advanced profiling is unavailable for the selected process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393827/android-studio-3-0-canary-8-advanced-profiling-is-unavailable-for-the-selected)